# I have a PPA, but I can't figure out how to add an image to the Software Center listing

Tags: software-center, ppa

So I have made a PPA: https://launchpad.net/~stefansundin/+archive/ubuntu/truecrypt

After adding the ppa and updating the sources, I can see it in the software center. It is using the default icon however, can I change that somehow or is that only possible for official packages?

Thank you!